# XGboost gives objective function error when used with SKlearn RandomseachCV

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am trying to run a random search using sklearn random search CV function to select hyperparameters for XGBoost for a regression task. Here is my code:

```
#search space
params_xgboost = {
 "learning_rate"    : [0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30],
 "max_depth"        : [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15],
 "min_child_weight" : [ 1, 3, 5, 7 ],
 "gamma"            : [ 0.0, 0.1, 0.2 , 0.3, 0.4 ],
 "colsample_bytree" : [ 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 , 0.7],
 'n_estimators'     : [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35],
 'objective': 'reg:squarederror' 
}

model = XGBRegressor()

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = model, 
                      param_distributions = params_xgboost, 
                      n_iter = 100, 
                      cv = 5, 
                      verbose=1, 
                      random_state=42,
                      scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', 
                      n_jobs = -1)

#params glare proba
random_search.fit(X_transform, Y['dgp'])
```

I am really struggling to understand why I am getting the following error

```
Unknown objective function: `u`
```

```
XGBoostError: [16:46:53] /Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/xgboost_1607604592557/work/src/objective/objective.cc:26: Unknown objective function: `u`
Objective candidate: survival:aft
Objective candidate: binary:hinge
Objective candidate: multi:softmax
Objective candidate: multi:softprob
Objective candidate: rank:pairwise
Objective candidate: rank:ndcg
Objective candidate: rank:map
Objective candidate: reg:squarederror
Objective candidate: reg:squaredlogerror
Objective candidate: reg:logistic
Objective candidate: reg:pseudohubererror
Objective candidate: binary:logistic
Objective candidate: binary:logitraw
Objective candidate: reg:linear
Objective candidate: count:poisson
Objective candidate: survival:cox
Objective candidate: reg:gamma
Objective candidate: reg:tweedie

Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) 1   libxgboost.dylib                    0x00000001210ad23e dmlc::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal() + 110
  [bt] (1) 2   libxgboost.dylib                    0x00000001211a4bd7 xgboost::ObjFunction::Create(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, xgboost::GenericParameter const*) + 759
  [bt] (2) 3   libxgboost.dylib                    0x0000000121168d06 xgboost::LearnerConfiguration::ConfigureObjective(xgboost::LearnerTrainParam const&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >*) + 1926
  [bt] (3) 4   libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000012115de1f xgboost::LearnerConfiguration::Configure() + 1247
  [bt] (4) 5   libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000012115e2e7 xgboost::LearnerImpl::UpdateOneIter(int, std::__1::shared_ptr<xgboost::DMatrix>) + 119
  [bt] (5) 6   libxgboost.dylib                    0x00000001210b1e5c XGBoosterUpdateOneIter + 156
  [bt] (6) 7   libffi.7.dylib                      0x0000000107c40ead ffi_call_unix64 + 85
  [bt] (7) 8   ???                                 0x00007ffee8691a00 0x0 + 140732797622784
```

I ran the same code on a separate classification task and it worked fine using the `multi:softmax` objective so I am not sure why in the above case I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objective='reg:squarederror'` is a default so you can safely omit it:

```
XGBRegressor?
```

---

```
Init signature: XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror', **kwargs)
Docstring:     
Implementation of the scikit-learn API for XGBoost regression.
```

Should you wish to specify it explicitly you can always do:

```
XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror'...)
```

Notice as well a note about `**kwargs` for sklearn API ([docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier)):

> **kwargs is unsupported by scikit-learn. We do not guarantee that parameters passed via this argument will interact properly with scikit-learn.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @SergeyBushmanov, but to clarify the error here: you haven't given a list of objectives, just the string `'reg:squarederror'`.  But since strings are iterables in python, the random search treats this as 16 objectives to try out: `'r'`, `'e'`, `'g'`, etc. (and the first one tried is `'u'`, as your error complains).  Adding list brackets around it should work; but again, for things you aren't actually interested in searching over, just specify them in the estimator as in @Sergey's answer.